# Show date from Parse database in UITableView section header

Tags: ios, uitableview, date, parse-platform

I'm building an app that retrieves items from a Parse database and inserts them into a `UITableView`. In my Parse database, each item has its own date (i.e. film dates). Now this is the part I’m having trouble with:

I would like to sort the items by their own date, with the date for that item being in the section header. I would also like to show only the items whose date is from the current date and onwards. Please also know that I’m using the latest version of iOS and using Objective-C. I have exhausted other sources but have yet to find exactly what I need. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Right now I have this in my ShowsTableViewController.m:

**My getShows method:**

```
-(void)getShows{
    PFQuery *retrieveShows = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"shows"];

   [retrieveShows findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError
*error) {
   //NSLog(@"%@", objects);
   if (!error)
   {
       _showsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
   }

   [showsTableView reloadData];

}];
}
```

And this is how I'm currently populating the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ShowsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"showsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *tempObject = [_showsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"title];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You will need to split the objects that are returned from parse into a number of arrays; probably an array of arrays will be simplest.  Then use each sub-array as a section. To make it easier to build the arrays, add a sort to your parse query to sort by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you require, I think you have to sort your data and put it in to a `Array`. And this `Array` will hold list of `Dictionary`. Each `Dictionary` will have two key (first key is `title`: and value of it is title you want show to `header`, second key is `data`: and value of it is array item in seciton)

And now you will implement `UITableViewDataSource` for it:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return [self.listData count];
}
```

for each section you can implement same like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   NSArray *data = [[self.listData objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"data"];
}
```

And show header:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [[self.listData objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"title"];
}
```

And show to cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   ShowsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"showsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   PFObject *tempObject = [[self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"title];

   return cell;
}
```

You can do this way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you briefly explain indexPathAtIndex please? I don't quite understand that part.

Comment: @Devonte ah sorry it should be `objectAtIndex`

Comment: Thanks! I'm very close to have what I need. In the method titleForHeaderInSection, when I insert "date" instead of "title" why doesn't it show the date in the header?

Comment: @Devonte You should get date and convert to NSString and show it.

Comment: And if you change key `title` to `date`, you have get data in this `[[self.listData objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"title"]` to `[[self.listData objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"date"]`

Comment: Ahh, of course! So, get the date and convert to NSString. Where would be ideal to put this code? In the titleForHeaderInSection method?

Comment: I think you should create Class Utilities and put some function like it to this class, show you can reuse it later and code will be more nicer.

Comment: maybe it like this `+(NSString *)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date withFormat:(NSString*)format
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    NSString* stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return stringFromDate;
}` and in titleforHeader callit [Utilites stringFromDate:yourDate withFormat:yourFormatYouWant ];